# PHP no error but data not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data from a form to mySQL DB, no connection error, but no data is inserted into my database. Any idea?
Here's my HTML form:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                    <b><em>Listen to the voice of Soul</em></b>
                    <form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="signup.php" accept-charset="UTF-8"id="signup-nav">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="email2">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"id="email2" name="signup_email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="password2">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd2" name="signup_pwd" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="password3">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdcon" name="signup_pwdcon" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="signUpBtn" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

My database name is coldplay, table is userdata and im using local host with ID=root, no password

PHP:

```
<?php

include ("dbh.php");

if(isset($_POST["signUpBtn"])){

$signup_email = $_POST ['signup_email'];
$signup_pwd = $_POST ['signup_pwd'];
$signup_pwdcon = $_POST ['signup_pwdcon'];

$sql_signup = "insert into userdata (email, pwd, pwdcon) 
values ('$signup_email', '$signup_pwd', '$signup_pwdcon')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql_signup);

mysqli_close($conn);

header("Location: testing.html");


}

?>
```

PHP database handler:

```
<? php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "coldplay");

if (!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you notice the space in your php tag from dbh.php file? First line it should read `<?php`

Comment: Please don't save plain passwords to database.

Comment: OH I just realized my mistake!  This is so dump THANK YOU SO MUCH @BenjaminPaap it's solved!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please first read about [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and [how to bind parameters to prepared statements in mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php). Your script is vulnerable to sql injection if you leave it like this.

There is a problem in your dbh.php file with the opening php tag. It should read `<?php` insteat of `<? php` (notice the space).

If that was not the problem you should check the result of your `mysqli_query` method like this:

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql_signup)) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```